# Working abroad,I build realtionships

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is my sentance

> While working  all over the globe, I build relationships with people from many different cultures.

I want to emphasize cultural awareness I have attained. How to formulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The relationships I built while working across the globe have taught me a great deal about many different cultures.